# What is the best way to create a HTML table with random numbers

Tags: jquery, html-table

I was able to use jQuery to create a random number and put it in a `<td>`. But can I make each `<td>` have its own random number?

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td').text(function(){
    return Math.random(); // or however you want to generate your random number
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dYnqv/).

The above iterates through each `td` element and sets its text independently of other `td` elements, unlike:

```
$('td').text(Math.random());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dYnqv/1/).

Which sets the *same* random number to *all* the `td` elements.

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped! If this has solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer, or clarify any problems that remain. =)